# Java compile error: List<Integer> cannot be converted to ArrayList<Integer>

Tags: java, list, arraylist

The program is like:

```
public class Proj {

    public List dsp(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = {4,3,2,7,8,2,3,1};
        List<Integer> bl = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int var : nums) {
            bl.add(var);
        }

        Proj p = new Proj();
        p.dsp(bl);
        System.out.println(bl);
    }
}
```

Error message:

> incompatible types: List cannot be converted to ArrayList 
>   at the line `p.dsp(bl);`

How to fix the error?

Comment: `dsp` accepts a `ArrayList`, but you make `bl` only be a `List`. And why does the method return a raw type?

Comment: does this compile?

Comment: Use `ArrayList<Integer>` as the return type for `dsp`.

Comment: @aquaballin Since OP is asking about a compile error, I imagine the answer to your question is probably NO.

Answer (score 4):

Not every `List<Integer>` is a `ArrayList<Integer>`. The `dsp` method accepts a `ArrayList<Integer>` so to make it work you'll pass a type `ArrayList<Integer>` or  change your method to accept `List<Integer>`.

Also, make use of generics, I'd use `List<Integer>` for the return type instead of `List`.

Answer (score 0):

You can‘t cast from parent to children, your dsp method should accept List in place of ArrayList